# Google Ads (Adwords): How does one "remove" or "unset" Campaign Groups?

Tags: advertising, google-ads

Google Ads (Adwords): How does one "remove" or "unset" Campaign Groups?

Not like this:
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6393350?hl=en#zippy=%2Cremove-a-campaign-group

[image]